# "Is a directory" error when copying specified directories from remote

Tags: linux, bash, remote-server, scp

I'm trying to download from remote last N directories using following script:

```
  echo "Downloading last $lastN failed tests..."
  RECENT=$(ssh $USER@$IP ls -1td $DIR/* | head -$lastN)
  scp -r $USER@$IP:"$RECENT" $TARGET
```

but it downloads only first file and throws errors for others:

```
bash: line 1: /some/path/test_2018-12-08-20-21-19: Is a directory
bash: line 2: /some/path/test_2018-12-07-15-08-53: Is a directory
bash: line 3: /some/path/test_2018-12-07-14-56-28: Is a directory
bash: line 4: /some/path/test_2018-12-07-14-54-12: Is a directory
```

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to iterate on all values of $RECENT variable, instead of specifying it at once to the scp command.

```
for recentElement in $RECENT; do
  scp -r $USER@$IP:"$recentElement " "$TARGET/"
done
```

But, you may need to adapt the way you create the `$TARGET` variable, are you sure it is a directory?

Did you consider using `rsync`, instead of `scp`?

Comment: Looping over files is not a solution because id_rsa passphrase has to be entered every time. As for `rsync` what are advantages over `scp`?

Comment: To avoid having to enter passphrase each time, you should consider using `ssh-agent`. About `rsync`, the main advantages will be 1. to be able to continue, in case of copy failure (scp will recopy everything). 2. rsync will check the copy is 100% OK at end.

Comment: `ssh-agent` + for loop solved my problem. Thank you ;)